# Switching window focus produces a small lag spike

Tags: unity, nvidia

Whenever I switch my window focus (i.e. Nautilus to System Monitor) it takes much longer than it should. I click, and then it switches after ~1 sec. Using System Monitor I noticed a larger than normal jump in CPU usage when switching windows. It seems to be prevalent for all applications.

CPU: i3-4170, using the microcode firmware

GPU: Nvidia GTX 950, running proprietary drivers

Comment: I have an i7-6700 and a GTX 960 with microcode and proprietary drivers, same as you and I'm having the same issue. Have you found a solution anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also seeing this on 16.04 with i5-4460 and a GTX 960 on a 32bit system (don't ask!)  I don't see it with nouveau drivers but I do with the NVidia proprietary ones (all I've tested up to 381.13.)

Probably the same issue as [CPU spikes and performance problems changing window focus in Unity/Ubuntu 16.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890888/cpu-spikes-and-performance-problems-changing-window-focus-in-unity-ubuntu-16-04).

Although not a proper solution, restarting unity by using `unity --replace` seems to work around the issue for that session. (You might need to try it again if it doesn't work first time.)

This could be related to [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1300892](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1300892). If you think that bug affects you then please do click "This bug affects me" at the top so that the maintainers get a good reflection of how many people this bug impacts as this is currently triaged as a low priority bug.

**EDIT: It seems that adding the command `/usr/bin/unity --replace` command to "Startup Applications" does work okay as a kludgy but less temporary workaround.  :)**

Comment: This worked for me. Though, not sure if a reboot would cause the issue again.