# CPU spikes and performance problems changing window focus in Unity/Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, unity, nvidia, xorg, compiz

I'm experiencing weird performance issues changing window focus with Unity. It happens no matter the combination of applications I have open, though gets worse the more there are (whether they're terminal windows or Chromium windows).

For example, if I'm editing a text file with gedit and then click on Chromium, it will take an actual full second to change focus (and vice versa, so I can't start typing right away). Running 'top' in term while switching windows shows Xorg using ~50% CPU and compiz will using ~10%.

I'm running an i5-4670 with a GTX 1070. I'm using the 378.13 Nvidia drivers, and the Intel processor microcode firmware. Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution? Thanks!

UPDATE: As indicated below, I've tried disabling intel_pstate and changing to the performance governor. I've also experimented with a single monitor configuration, as well as Unity's Low Graphics Mode. No dice on any of these unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also seeing this on 16.04 with i5-4460 and a GTX 960 on a 32bit system (don't ask!) I don't see it with nouveau drivers but I do with the NVidia proprietary ones (all I've tested up to 381.13.)

Although not a proper solution, restarting unity by using `unity --replace` seems to work around the issue for that session.  (You might need to try it again if it doesn't work first time.)

This could be related to [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1300892](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1300892).  If you think that bug affects you then please do click "This bug affects me" at the top so that the maintainers get a good reflection of how many people this bug impacts as this is currently triaged as a low priority bug.

**EDIT: It seems that adding the command `/usr/bin/unity --replace` command to "Startup Applications" does work okay as a kludgy but less temporary workaround.  :)**

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue after updating and upgrading. The problem for me was related to CPU clocking speed. You might give this a try.

1. Disable intel_psate. You can do this by modifying `/etc/default/grub` and adding `intel_pstate=disable` parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. It should look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"`.
2. Then save the file and run  `sudo update-grub`.
3. Install cpufrequtils package: `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils`.
   Edit `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils` file and set the following line to the governor you need (performance in my case): `GOVERNOR=”performance”`
4. reboot

This is a hardware specific solution to Intel processors.

Comment: If you are going to use performance mode anyway, then there is no difference between the acpi-cpufreq and intel_pstate CPU frequency drivers. Without specific evidence that it is the root issue, I would not suggest disabling the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. However, I definitely agree to do so as a test (i.e. to help obtain evidence).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both disabling intel_pstate and setting my governor to "performance" (as well as having both at the same time) but I didn't notice any changes - still the lag changing window focus unfortunately.